# Pros and cons of injecting dependencies through code or configuratoin

Tags: c#, structuremap

I know structuremap is used for IoC in C#. It can be hooked via two ways. Through configuration:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
      x.UseDefaultStructureMapConfigFile = true;
});

<StructureMap>
    <DefaultInstance PluginType="XXXXXXX, YYYYYY" PluggedType="AAAAA,BBBBB" Scope="PerRequest" />
</StructureMap>
```

And from code, like this:

```
ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
{
     x.UseDefaultStructureMapConfigFile = false;
     x.AddRegistry<StructureMapRegistry>();
});

HttpContextLifecycle cycle = new HttpContextLifecycle();
For<IDataRepository<MethodName>>().LifecycleIs(cycle).Use<MethodName>();
```

I want to know what are the pros and cons of both approaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Configuration:

  - Pro: you can alter it without having to recompile.
  - Con: no static typing. A typo in a type or interface name can go unnoticed until runtime.
- Code:

  - Pro: static typing. Not possible to compile with unknown or incompatible types.
  - Con: you can't alter it without having to recompile.

Comment: Is there any performance difference between these two approaches

Comment: The answer to that is either "it's unnoticeable", "you shouldn't care" or "go benchmark", pick any.